# R128gain documentation

Tags: command-line, cmd

I'm trying to find a way to measure LUFS loudness from the command line in windows. I found R128 gain which seems to offer a solution but I cannt find a way to install it from the latest download (which is here : http://r128gain.sourceforge.net/#usage).

Can anyone help me understand what I need to to do to install and access via the command line?

Comment: Download the [latest 32/64 bit version from this page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bs1770gain/files/bs1770gain/0.4.12/) and unzip to a location of your liking?

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end!

1)Download correct package for operating system
2)Unzip download
3)Add entry to PATH environmental variable (in the case of Windows)
4)Restart the terminal